# Readability in array access

Tags: javascript, arrays, readability

So I'm currently writing a javascript game ([here](http://gdriv.es/derivclicker/game.html) with javascript [here](https://googledrive.com/host/0B-iZ3pL0D494SEVwR3MzcDQ1MGc/js/script.js)). Currently, for the buildings on the inventory page, I store their amounts in an array called "buildings", with each index corresponding to a particular building. Then, when I need the amount of a building owned for anything, I use something like buildings[0].

The problem is, this is fairly hard to understand! buildings[0] doesn't really tell someone looking at the code what exactly it is. I'm wondering if there's any way to make this easier to understand?

Comment: JavaScript has objects (key/value pairs). You're already using them in your code, so why not use them for `buildings` too?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has Objects:

```
var myCar = new Object();
myCar.make = "Ford";
myCar.model = "Mustang";
myCar.year = 1969;
```

The above example is from [MDN's Working With Objects article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

An example in your situation:

```
var buildings = {
    "John's House": {
        floors: 2,
        resource: "brick"
    },
    "Alice's House": {
        floors: 1,
        resource: "wood"
    }
};
```

You can then pull the object values using:

```
buildings["John's House"].floors; // 2
```

And even loop through them:

```
for (var key in buildings) {
    var building = buildings[key];
    console.log(building.resource);
}
```

Comment: Should I be removing the arrays, then? The array structure's really helpful in terms of shortening the code.

Comment: I guess that's not actually the right way to put it. Arrays let me compress all the "buy building" functions into a single function, to which I pass the index corresponding to the building.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the equivalent of an [enumerable type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type)?

```
var player = {
    buildingTypes: {
      deriv1: 0,
      combinatorics: 1,
      computer: 3,
      high_schooler: 4,
      etc...
    }
}
```

Then you can use something like:

```
var building_selected = player.buildingTypes.deriv1;
```